# How to fix a warnings with onesignal in flutter - warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast

Tags: android, flutter, dart, onesignal

I am developing flutter applications and I need a notification system, the most complete I found was oneSignal, but it generates some warnings in my app, could someone explain me and maybe resolve?

Below the warnings generated after I add to my android / build.gradle the following code: 
 `tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
 }`

```
C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\onesignal_flutter-2.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\onesignal\flutter\OneSignalPlugin.java:143: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
      OneSignal.addTriggers((Map<String, Object>) arguments);
                                                  ^
  required: Map<String,Object>
  found:    Object

C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\onesignal_flutter-2.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\onesignal\flutter\OneSignalPlugin.java:154: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
      OneSignal.removeTriggersForKeys((Collection<String>) arguments);
                                                           ^
  required: Collection<String>
  found:    Object

C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\onesignal_flutter-2.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\onesignal\flutter\OneSignalPlugin.java:242: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject((Map<String, Object>) call.arguments);
                                                               ^
  required: Map<String,Object>
  found:    Object

C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\onesignal_flutter-2.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\onesignal\flutter\OneSignalTagsController.java:89: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
            OneSignal.sendTags(new JSONObject((Map<String, Object>) call.arguments), new OSFlutterChangeTagsHandler(registrar, channel, result));
                                                                        ^
  required: Map<String,Object>
  found:    Object

C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\onesignal_flutter-2.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\onesignal\flutter\OneSignalTagsController.java:91: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
            OneSignal.deleteTags((List<String>)call.arguments, new OSFlutterChangeTagsHandler(registrar, channel, result));
                                                   ^
  required: List<String>
  found:    Object
5 warnings
```